# How to find hyperlinks with XPath

Tags: xpath, href

I've tried

```
.//*[@id='post-31']/div/div/div/a[1]
```

on this input:

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

<div class="entry-content">
    <div class="myaccount">
        <div class="user-profile-links">
            <a href="http://store.demoqa.com/products-page/your-account/?tab=purchase_history">Purchase History</a>
            |
            <a class="current" href="http://store.demoqa.com/products-page/your-account/?tab=edit_profile">Your Details</a>
            |
            <a href="http://store.demoqa.com/products-page/your-account/?tab=downloads">Your Downloads</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this really the whole input document (there's no element with id `post-31`)? What is the context node your XPath expression is evaluated against (you might want to use `//` instead of `.//`)?

Answer (score 0):

For the example you posted, there is no root element with an id-attribute, which would explain why it wouldn't work. The xpath expression

```
/div/div/div/a[1]/@href
```

finds the href for the first a-element.